# How can I check the most recent date and get the right cell information in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I need a macro that check the most recent date on the left in a column and get the information from the cell on the right in VBA.

I can't order by most recent because each column in the same sheet has different date for different purpose. So this is why I need a macro to check what specific cell on the left in the row has the most recent date and pull the information from the cell on the right.

In the example as follow below, I want the loginB because is the most recent collected:

| A header | header | Header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fri Dec 30 04:17:43 UTC 2022 | loginA | Thu Dec 29 04:17:43 UTC 2022 |
| Sun Jan 01 04:17:43 UTC 2023 | loginB | Fri Dec 30 04:17:43 UTC 2022 |

Does anyone have an idea to share?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro that copies the data to another worksheet, replacing UTC with a blank choice and then ordering from highest to lowest. So I got the information I needed. I think it's possible to parse in Json, but for my needs it's working fine so far.